# textarea focus not working on chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to implement a textarea with on click focus which removes the placeholder text. It is working in Firefox and IE but not Chrome. Not sure if I am doing something silly here...

HTML:

```
<textarea id="bio" name="user_bio" placeholder="Hi, I am a member of Footdrive!"></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
/*Input fields focus and text transparency*/

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
     color: transparent;
}

 input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
     color: transparent;
}

 input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}


/*Biography field focus and text transparency*/

textarea:focus::-webkit-textarea-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

 textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}

textarea:focus:-ms-textarea-placeholder {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: @Joum yh mate even though none of that worked and someone posting here just did a perfect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct solution is the same than input:

```
textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{
  color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: -webkit-textarea-placeholder does not exist

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks. Now that I look at the code it makes complete sense!

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
textarea:focus::-webkit-textarea-placeholder {
    content: "";
}
```